# Worklight WLWebView vs. WebView

Tags: android, webview, ibm-mobilefirst, calabash

I am working on automation testing for a IBM Worklight application using the calabash-android and calabash-cucumber(ios) gems.  Keep in mind that I am not a developer on the actual application.

My problem is that Worklight names the android webView "WLWebview" rather than simply "webView".  Calabash hates this and I've gone into many of the methods inside calabash-android and tried to remove the exceptions without much success.

What I have been able to do is find the lower level methods inside calabash-android and use these to access webView objects.  This is creating a layer of abstraction in my testing framework.  The iOS app created by Worklight simply creates a webview named "webView" and works flawlessly.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid building this layer of abstraction.  Does anyone know if Worklight can deploy an Android app without naming the webView "WLWebView" and simply "webView"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if Worklight can deploy an Android app without
>   naming the webView "WLWebView" and simply "webView"?

There is no feature inside Worklight that allows you change `WLWebview` to `Webview`. Furthermore, unless you figure out a way to change the name inside the generated `worklight-android.jar`, you're unfortunately out of luck.

As a side note, unlike Worklight, [calabash-android](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android) is an open source project. It would be good if you could contribute via a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) code that handles the WebView regardless of the name.

Comment: Thanks cnandreu.
I figured this would be something calabash-android needs to accommodate.  I'll start looking into the source some more.